# What is the formula for resolution for longitude (for latitude works perfectly) (google maps)?

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

The expression of geography phenomenon and geography features is multi-scale.
The scale represents the comprehension extent and location precision of ground features. 
The resolution and scale are usually used to measure the scale. The resolution in GIS, is also called Ground Resolution or Spatial Resolution, which represents the actual distance that a pixel represents. 
Take **googlemap** for example: `The zoom level is 1`

There are four pictures whose size is `256*256`. 
The spatial resolution of the equator is: Earth equatorial circumference (the actual distance) divided by `256 * 2` (the pixel size). The resolution of other latitudes is: `the length of latitude circle / 512`.

So it can be seen, the resolution is determined by two factors: 
latitude and zoom level.

The zoom level determines the pixel number. The latitude determines the ground distance. So the resolution of **googlemap** in certain view can be calculated by the following formula (unit: `meter/pixel`):

```
F(X,Y) = (cos(X*PI/180)*2*PI*R)/(256*2^Y)

F(X,Y): Map resolution;
X: Latitude;
Y: Zoom level;
R: Constant 6378137 represents earth radius.
Unit: meter.
```

What is the formula for resolution for longitude  (for latitude  works perfectly)? (google maps)

Comment: for longitude it depends on the latitude. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Answer (score 0):

There is a Google Maps function that allows you to find the bounding box of a map.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  //get the bounds:
  console.log(map.getBounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This will log something like this:

```
-35.841477973835374, 153.5718564453125
-32.92715336680372, 147.7161435546875
```

A Google Map uses the Mercator Projection. This means that the longitude stretches from one side of the map relative to the other. However, an accurate approximation can be taken from the difference between the longitudes divided by the width of the screen.